# Two commands for one button

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

I have a button on a View. The command for this button should should bind two ICommands. One is in the ViewModel which does the saving. The other ICommand is in the code behind of the view and does some animation stuff.

I'm able to call either of this two commands with the binding in the View. But how can I call both commands in a row with just one click on the button? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Create a third `ICommand`, which is bound to the button and invokes the other two commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephen. Where do I need to add this third ICommand. In code behind of view or in ViewModel? Then I have the same problem as desribed above. How can I invoke a command from the ViewModel in the code behind or the other way round. Thanks for your heolp!

Comment: I would say in the VM, but the animation makes it tricky. Have you read [Josh Smith's book](http://www.advancedmvvm.com/)? He covers MVVM design with animations.